# Apache Load Balancing And Network traffic Flow

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, traffic

I am using apache load balancing to load balance web requests to various other nodes, the problem I am having is during uploads and downloads, all the traffic is also being routed through my load balancing node, which is also the node serving up pages and its being bogged down, which is undesirable, does anyone have any suggestions of how to go about resolving this issue? Will the head node (load balancer) always have all traffic go through it?

Thanks

Daniel

Comment: apache as a load balancer.... hmmmm... try nginx or haproxy even better

Comment: @nandoP either way, wont all traffic go through the head node ? since requests are made to that node?

Comment: yes traffic will return to "head node" but some daemons are better able to handle without being "bogged down", even when doubleduty as lb and responding to http (ie nginx)... apache has its place.... lb is not one of them

Answer (score 0):

If it is a load-balancer, then yes. If it is a rerouting balancer, then no. You could also set up something that receives the initial request and then redirects the user to a processing server. That's a theoretical answer as I don't know what software you would use, etc.

I would like to point out, however, this example: https://stackexchange.com/performace . Maybe you are trying to solve the wrong problem.